# MultiIndex Dataframe Bar Plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram, multi-index

```
                Item
Date M&Y State      
2019-09  CH        4
2019-10  CH        2
2019-11  CH        7
         DE        6
2020-02  CH        7
2020-04  CH       19
         DE        1
         LI        1
```

```
plt.figure()
states = ['CH','DE','LI']
#states = ['CH','DE','LI','Total']
pos = np.arange(len(states))
occ = [19,1,1]
#occ = [19,1,1,21]
bars = plt.bar(pos, occ, align='center')
#bars = plt.bar(pos, occ, align='center', linewidth=0, color='lightslategrey')
bars[0].set_color('#1F77B4')
bars[1].set_color('#F26419')
bars[2].set_color('#F6AE2D')
plt.xticks(pos, states, alpha=0.8)
plt.title('April Items', alpha=0.8)
plt.tick_params(top='off', bottom='off', left='off', right='off', labelleft='off', labelbottom='on')
for spine in plt.gca().spines.values():
    spine.set_visible(False)
for bar in bars:
    plt.gca().text(bar.get_x() + bar.get_width()/2, bar.get_height() - 5, str(int(bar.get_height())), 
                 ha='center', color='w', fontsize=11)
plt.show()
```

From this dataframe I would like to plot a bar plot with:

- *Date M&Y* on the x-axis
- Change *Date M&Y* format (e.g. 2019-09: Sep 2019)
- For each *Date M&Y* there are up to three *State* values (DE, CH, LI)
- I would like to plot them both stacked and not (maybe in two adjacent subplots)

So far I could only work on April data as an example because I could not handle MultiIndex.

I am still very new to python and your help is really appreciated!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dckRP.png)

Comment: What have you tried so far ?

Comment: @Alesandre I edited my post